# My scrapy shell loads forever and gives timeout twisted.internet.error.TimeoutError:

Tags: python-3.x, xpath, web-scraping, scrapy

I had issues with my spiders which were not delivery imports, I then took their `start_urls` and try to find the bugs using `scrapy shell`. Unfortunately even the scrapy shell is loading forever and comes back with `twisted.internet.error.TimeoutError`, how do I solve this ? kindly see my scrapy shell comand an error below

````
root@cf59900d79a8:/workspace# scrapy shell "https:www.mystart_url.com"
2020-08-28 04:37:53 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Scrapy 1.5.0 started (bot: crawler)
2020-08-28 04:37:53 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Versions: lxml 4.5.2.0, libxml2 2.9.10, cssselect 1.1.0, parsel 1.6.0, w3lib 1.22.0, Twisted 20.3.0, Python 3.5.9 (default, Jul 22 2020, 13:58:49) - [GCC 8.3.0], pyOpenSSL 19.1.0 (OpenSSL 1.1.1g  21 Apr 2020), cryptography 3.0, Platform Linux-4.19.76-linuxkit-x86_64-with-debian-10.4
2020-08-28 04:37:53 [scrapy.crawler] INFO: Overridden settings: {'DUPEFILTER_CLASS': 'scrapy_splash.SplashAwareDupeFilter', 'DOWNLOAD_TIMEOUT': 40, 'NEWSPIDER_MODULE': 'crawler.spiders', 'USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/55.0.2883.95 Safari/537.36', 'FEED_FORMAT': 'json', 'FEED_URI': 'http://azurite:10000/devstoreaccount1/%(feed_name)s.json', 'SPIDER_MODULES': ['crawler.spiders'], 'MAIL_FROM': 'scraping.info@yahoo.com', 'MAIL_USER': 'scraping.info@yahoo.com', 'CONCURRENT_REQUESTS': 60, 'AUTOTHROTTLE_MAX_DELAY': 5.0, 'LOG_FORMATTER': 'crawler.middlewares.PoliteLogFormatter', '*****': 'hgyTvvty43q', 'LOGSTATS_INTERVAL': 0, 'COOKIES_ENABLED': False, 'REACTOR_THREADPOOL_MAXSIZE': 60, 'AUTOTHROTTLE_START_DELAY': 0.1, 'MAIL_HOST': 'smtp.mail.yahoo.com', 'DOWNLOAD_DELAY': 0.25, 'BOT_NAME': 'crawler', 'HTTPCACHE_STORAGE': 'scrapy_splash.SplashAwareFSCacheStorage', 'CONCURRENT_REQUESTS_PER_DOMAIN': 6, 'RETRY_HTTP_CODES': [500, 502, 503, 504, 522, 524, 408, 429, 403], 'AUTOTHROTTLE_ENABLED': True, 'AUTOTHROTTLE_TARGET_CONCURRENCY': 5.0, 'RETRY_TIMES': 10, 'LOG_LEVEL': 'INFO'}
2020-08-28 04:37:54 [scrapy.extensions.feedexport] ERROR: Unknown feed storage scheme: http
2020-08-28 04:37:54 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled extensions:
['scrapy.extensions.corestats.CoreStats',
 'scrapy.extensions.memusage.MemoryUsage',
 'scrapy.extensions.throttle.AutoThrottle',
 'scrapy.extensions.telnet.TelnetConsole',
 'crawler.extensions.ItemLogStats',
 'crawler.extensions.StatsMailer']
2020-08-28 04:37:54 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled downloader middlewares:
['scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpauth.HttpAuthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.downloadtimeout.DownloadTimeoutMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.defaultheaders.DefaultHeadersMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry.RetryMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.MetaRefreshMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.RedirectMiddleware',
 'scrapy_splash.SplashCookiesMiddleware',
 'scrapy_splash.SplashMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpproxy.HttpProxyMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcompression.HttpCompressionMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.stats.DownloaderStats']
2020-08-28 04:37:54 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled spider middlewares:
['scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror.HttpErrorMiddleware',
 'scrapy_splash.SplashDeduplicateArgsMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite.OffsiteMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.referer.RefererMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.urllength.UrlLengthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.depth.DepthMiddleware']
2020-08-28 04:37:54 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled item pipelines:
['crawler.pipelines.DuplicatesPipeline',
 'crawler.pipelines.DateWorker',
 'crawler.pipelines.CustomImagesPipeline',
 'scrapy_jsonschema.JsonSchemaValidatePipeline',
 'crawler.pipelines.OutAttachmentProcessing',
 'crawler.pipelines.IgnoreNullValues',
 'crawler.pipelines.ItemLogStats']
2020-08-28 04:37:54 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/scrapy", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(execute())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/scrapy/cmdline.py", line 150, in execute
    _run_print_help(parser, _run_command, cmd, args, opts)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/scrapy/cmdline.py", line 90, in _run_print_help
    func(*a, **kw)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/scrapy/cmdline.py", line 157, in _run_command
    cmd.run(args, opts)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/scrapy/commands/shell.py", line 73, in run
    shell.start(url=url, redirect=not opts.no_redirect)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/scrapy/shell.py", line 48, in start
    self.fetch(url, spider, redirect=redirect)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/scrapy/shell.py", line 115, in fetch
    reactor, self._schedule, request, spider)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/twisted/internet/threads.py", line 122, in blockingCallFromThread
    result.raiseException()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/twisted/python/failure.py", line 488, in raiseException
    raise self.value.with_traceback(self.tb)
twisted.internet.error.TimeoutError: User timeout caused connection failure: Getting https:www.mystart_url.com took longer than 40.0 seconds..
root@cf59900d79a8:/workspace# ```
````

Comment: Could you share your settings.py file

Comment: did you mean "https://www.mystart_url.com"

Answer (score 0):

Setting a delay between downloading pages from a site can help with timeout errors resulting from too frequent requests to it. This is done via the DOWNLOAD_DELAY parameter in the project's settings.py file.

The Scrapy documentation has this to say:

`The amount of time (in secs) that the downloader should wait before downloading consecutive pages from the same website. This can be used to throttle the crawling speed to avoid hitting servers too hard. Decimal numbers are supported`